# Selecting k rows with each value

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
NAME    SURNAME
John    Smith
Jane    Smith
Alice   Smith
James   Bond
James   Cameroon
David   Beckham
```

---

I've got a db and I want to select `k` rows with each `SURNAME`. For `k=1` it's:

```
SELECT * FROM people GROUP BY SURNAME;
```

and the output is:

```
Alice   Smith
James   Bond
James   Cameroon
David   Beckham
```

I can't find a way to query for `k=2`, where I would get (if present) 2 Smiths, 2 Bonds, 2 Cameroons etc or in general: k Smiths, k Bonds, k Cameroons etc. If there are less then k people with this `SURNAME` select all of them. Is it possible in `MySQL`?

Comment: I believe you should look and having clause

Comment: @apomene I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: If `k=2` and there is only `1` `Bond`, should this value be selected?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes, I'll add it to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME
FROM (
  SELECT NAME, SURNAME,
         @rn := IF(@s = SURNAME, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@s := SURNAME, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @s = '') AS vars
  ORDER BY SURNAME) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 3
```

The above query shows an example for `k=3`. It will select all records from the sample table cited in the OP.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f79eab/3)

Comment: That's art! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,Surname,Count(SurName) AS k FROM people 
GROUP BY SURNAME
HAVING k>=2
```

Comment: It only adds a column to the result. It's a wrong answer :/

Answer (score -1):

You can can distinct for the `surname` and join it with the same tables but limited to your `k`. this way you will get for each `surname` `k` rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`surname`)
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT `name` FROM `people` p2 where p2.surname = p1.surname limit 2
        ) x
FROM `people` p1
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".